# how to combine a array into itself?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

If I do `print_r($pieces);` I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Albany, NY
)
Array
(
    [0] => Albany, NY
    [1] => Albuquerque, NM
    [2] => Atlanta, GA
    [3] => Augusta, ME
    [4] => Billings, MT
    [5] => Baltimore, MD
)
Array
(
    [0] => Albany, NY
    [1] => Albuquerque, NM
    [2] => Atlanta, GA
    [3] => Augusta, ME
    [4] => Billings, MT
    [5] => Birmingham, AL
    [6] => Boise, ID
    [7] => Boston, MA
    [8] => Buffalo, NY
    [9] => Charleston, SC
    [10] => Charleston, WV
)
.....
```

What I need to do is to combine this arrays to get unique values.
First I need to split it in multiple arrays and then use `array_combine`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "I need to combine these arrays but first they need to be split apart and then combined" is what I got out of that. What are you actually asking?

Comment: i believe the way to do this is to split the array in multiple ones then combine them again, not sure though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$unique = array();
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    $unique = array_merge($unique, $piece);
}
$unique = array_unique($unique);
```

Or, if you're using PHP 5.3+:

```
array_unique(array_reduce($pieces, function ($a, $p) { return array_merge($a, $p); }, array()));
```

Comment: i get `Argument #2 is not an array` on both examples

Comment: @Patrioticcow Then your example data is incorrect or misleading.

Comment: Comment out the `$unique = ...` part and put `var_dump($piece)` and see what its outputting. deceze's example assumes that `$pieces` is an array containing arrays.

Comment: if i print_r($piece) i get `Albany, NY
Albany, NY
Albuquerque, NM
Atlanta, GA
Augusta, ME
Billings, MT
Baltimore, MD
Albany, NY
Albuquerque, NM.......
` as strings

Comment: Looks like `$piece` is a string, not an array.

Comment: shorter version of above : `array_unique(array_reduce($pieces, 'array_merge', []));`

Answer (score 0):

Bouni's comment has the best answer:

array_unique(array_reduce($pieces, 'array_merge', []));